# Speed up NLP cleaning preprocessing by multiprocessing/parallelisation

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, nlp, python-multiprocessing, ray

All in the title, I have to clean up a list of sentences varying from 10 000 to 100 000 with a whole cleaning pipeline before tokenization for an NLP clustering subject, I am looking for a way to optimize performance on list operations.

On the cleaning pipeline there is a part where I need to search and replace expression (I use re.sub with a dictionary)
Until now it was working well, but now the dictionary has increased to 5000 expressions (10x more). Time complexity is like n * w * rw (n number of sentences, m number of words, rw number of regex expression)). The execution cluster has 32 CPUs, that's why I think it could be a solution.

I tried to use python multiprocessing but I've encountered well known issues such as Pickle problems.. The code is implemented in classes and I don't want to transform all the code. Besides, I'm looking for a "best practice" solution. I've found that multiprocessing with python is awkward.

I'm currently exploring solutions such as ray, pyspark ..

What would be the best practice to clean up a text with best performances?

I have never saw a ressource or course that talk about this specific task for cleaning very long corpus.

Comment: There are many ways. The simplest one is to split your data into N part with N the number of available cores, then run your program N times in parallel. It also depends if you have access to resources such as a computing cluster, that can make a huge difference of course. I'd recommend to roughly estimate the duration in advance using proportionality, depending on number of cores available.

Comment: If you need help exploring how to use Ray, I'd recommend going to the Ray slack and asking people there! If you have a Ray specific question, happy to answer here :)

Comment: You can use your function with Fugue to run on top of Spark, Dask, or Ray. Hard to tell what is unpickleable from the post but you can get around it normally by instantiating the classes inside the function and only returning basic types.

There is an example here: https://fugue-tutorials.readthedocs.io/tutorials/applications/use_cases/nlp.html